# Co-located caching for web roles during VIP swap

Tags: session, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

When using co-located caching, what happens during a VIP swap?

I would image that the session state would be cleared (or at least to some extent?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct.  If you are storing session state in either Colocated or Dedicated Cache and swapping a new deployment into production slot, the cache and all of the session data in it, is cleared and lost.

Consider using Shared Cache or storing your session data in storage/SQLAzure if this behaviour is not desirable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  We can schedule deployments around user activity.